# Pthreads vs. OpenMP

Tags: c, pthreads, openmp

I'm creating a multi-threaded application in C using Linux.

I'm unsure whether I should use the POSIX thread API or the OpenMP API.

What are the pros & cons of using either?

**Edit:**

Could someone clarify whether both APIs create **kernel-level** or **user-level** threads?

Comment: Re: your edit (kernel- or user-level?) - it depends on the implementation! An API is just that - an **interface**. OpenMP is not the implementation - [but these are some implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Implementations). (There's a bit of info in [this Wikipedia article, too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library)).

Comment: Basically, if you can do what you need in OpenMP, you should do it in OpenMP.

Comment: OpenMP should be used for loops that have to be computed on all the cores. PThread can do that too but that's a lot of work and it is very hard to maintain, you use PThread usually if you need to start a separate process which shouldn't block the main thread. For example: you have a server, clients connect and have to keep the connection with the server and speak with it, you create a thread per client and work with the client in that thread without blocking the main thread. It's like you create a new application and let it run on the Operating System without bothering the main application.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935467/parallelization-pthreads-or-openmp

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Pthreads and OpenMP represent two totally different multiprocessing paradigms.

[Pthreads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) is a very low-level API for working with threads. Thus, you have extremely fine-grained control over thread management (create/join/etc), mutexes, and so on. It's fairly bare-bones.

On the other hand, [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) is *much* higher level, is more portable and doesn't limit you to using C. It's also much more easily scaled than pthreads. One specific example of this is OpenMP's work-sharing constructs, which let you divide work across multiple threads with relative ease. (See also Wikipedia's [pros and cons list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Pros_and_cons).)

That said, you've really provided no detail about the specific program you're implementing, or how you plan on using it, so it's fairly impossible to recommend one API over the other.

Answer (score 27):

If you use OpenMP, it *can* be as simple as adding a single pragma, and you'll be 90% of the way to properly multithreaded code with linear speedup.  To get the same performance boost with pthreads takes a lot more work.

But as usual, you get more flexibility with pthreads.

Basically, it depends on what your application is.  Do you have a trivially-parallelisable algorithm?  Or do you just have lots of arbitrary tasks that you'd like to simultaneously?  How much do the tasks need to talk to each other?  How much synchronisation is required?

Comment: Answering questions with questions... tsk ;) It would be great if you clarified how the answers to those questions actually affect the decision to use pthreads vs OpenMP.

Answer (score 9):

OpenMP has the advantages of being cross platform, and simpler for some operations.  It handles threading in a different manner, in that it gives you higher level threading options, such as parallelization of loops, such as:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    arr[i] = 2 * i;
```

If this interests you, and if C++ is an option, I'd also recommend [Threading Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/).

Pthreads is a lower level API for generating threads and synchronization explicitly.  In that respect, it provides more control.

Comment: POSIX threads, being part of the POSIX standard, are cross-platform. OpenMP, not being present in any operating system or C language standard I know of, is not cross-platform, unless you have a really strange idea of what cross-platform means.

Comment: @R. - OpenMP is indeed cross-platform, even if not formally standardized, with both C++ and C APIs. cf. Boost in the C++ world - not a de jure standard, but a de facto standard.

Comment: @R..: I'm not sure what you mean, the OpenMP C API standard is available in this spec (http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/cspec20.pdf).  Unless you meant, not standardized by IEEE/ANSI/ISO?

Comment: Anyone can write an API spec and call it a "standard". That doesn't make it one. The language of my comment was pretty clear to explain this anyway though: "not being present in any **operating system or C language standard**".

Comment: This is like saying OpenGL is not cross platform because it's neither part of C nor any operating system

Answer (score 5):

It depends on 2 things- your code base and your place within it. The key questions are- 1) "Does you code base have threads, threadpools, and the control primitives (locks, events, etc.)" and 2) "Are you developing reusable libraries or ordinary apps?"

If your library has thread tools (almost always built on some flavor of PThread), USE THOSE. If you are a library developer, spend the time (if possible) to build them. It is worth it- you can put together much more fine-grained, advanced threading than OpenMP will give you.

Conversely, if you are pressed for time or just developing apps or something off of 3rd party tools, use OpenMP. You can wrap it in a few macros and get the basic parallelism you need.

In general, OpenMP is good enough for basic multi-threading. Once you start getting to the point that you're managing system resourced directly on building highly async code, its ease-of-use advantage gets crowded out by performance and interface issues.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way. On a linux system, it is very highly likely that the OpenMP API itself uses `pthreads` to implement its features such as parallelism, barriers and locks/mutex. Having said that, there are good reasons to work directly with the pthreads API.

It is my opinion that -

You use OpenMP when -

- Your program contains easy to spot `for` loops where each iteration is independent from other.
- You want to retain the readability of the program. (Basically keep the parallelized program looking like the sequential version)
- You want to stay away from the nitty-gritty details of how threads are spawned and controlled at a micro level.

And pthreads when -

- You don't have easy to parallelize loops.
- You have different tasks which need to be performed concurrently, you might be wanting to give different responsibilities to each of those tasks.
- You want to control the flow of thread execution at a micro level.

Feel free to correct me in the comments.