# OpenMP vs C++11 threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

In the following example the C++11 threads take about 50 seconds to execute, but the OMP threads only 5 seconds.  Any ideas why?  (I can assure you it still holds true if you are doing real work instead of `doNothing`, or if you do it in a different order, etc.)  I'm on a 16 core machine, too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void doNothing() {}

int run(int algorithmToRun)
{
    auto startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    for(int j=1; j<100000; ++j)
    {
        if(algorithmToRun == 1)
        {
            vector<thread> threads;
            for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
            {
                threads.push_back(thread(doNothing));
            }
            for(auto& thread : threads) thread.join();
        }
        else if(algorithmToRun == 2)
        {
            #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(16)
            for(unsigned i=0; i<16; i++)
            {
                doNothing();
            }
        }
    }

    auto endTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = endTime - startTime;

    return elapsed_seconds.count();
}

int main()
{
    int cppt = run(1);
    int ompt = run(2);

    cout<<cppt<<endl;
    cout<<ompt<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that OpenMP is smart enough to optimize out the whole loop since it's a NOP. With ``threads`` you're suffering the overhead of spinning up and tearing down all those NOP threads. Try adding some actual code to the test function and see what happens.

Comment: Well, one thing is that you're using a dynamically resizing container to hold the threads; that can't help with performance.

Comment: Try just using a fixed sized array and initiating all its elements when created.

Comment: @aruisdante: I have added real code, and I can assure you the difference persists (I had lots of code and factored it down to post on here)--it's not due to the NOP.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: I've done that (and just tried again), and the difference is negligible, as the call to thread() calls new anyway. Good point though--But I also can assure you that that does not affect the performance.

Comment: likely comes down to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949901/pthreads-vs-openmp on Linux

Answer (score 40, accepted):

OpenMP [thread-pools for its Pragmas](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#LoopDirectiveFor) (also [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/choosing-between-openmp-and-explicit-threading-methods) and [here](http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=136)). Spinning up and tearing down threads is expensive. OpenMP avoids this overhead, so all it's doing is the actual work and the minimal shared-memory shuttling of the execution state. In your `Threads` code you are spinning up and tearing down a new set of 16 threads every iteration.

Comment: Thanks.  This _has_ to be the answer, but wouldn't you almost think that it would require a #pragma around the outer for loop?  Also, how do you know that as a fact--I don't see information about it in the documentation, even in the linked site.  I'm sure that you're right, I just want to back up the information.  I haven't ever read, as a fact, that they do that.

Comment: Check out the second link, there's some talk in there. I can try and find more solid documentation, I know I've read it explicitly somewhere.

Comment: [here](http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=136) is another discussion about it. Basically, it's actually not defined by the OpenMP standard, but most implementations on most platforms seem to do it if it's more efficient.

Comment: Thanks again :).  I figured it had to be threadpools, but I just surprisingly couldn't find it stated anywhere.  After looking some more, I found [this](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/optaps/common/optaps_par_multicore_thrdpool.htm).  I'm going to try it on a non-intel machine and see if it still holds true.

You beat me to it--It does look like it's basically done in all implementations.

Comment: PS. I can confirm the difference also exists on AMD machines.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a code of an 100 looping at 
[Choosing the right threading framework](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/choosing-the-right-threading-framework) and it took
OpenMP 0.0727, Intel TBB 0.6759 and C++ thread library 0.5962 mili-seconds.

I also applied what AruisDante suggested;

```
void nested_loop(int max_i, int band)  
{
    for (int i = 0; i < max_i; i++)
    {
        doNothing(band);
    }
}
...
else if (algorithmToRun == 5)
{
    thread bristle(nested_loop, max_i, band);
    bristle.join();
}
```

This code looks like taking less time than your original C++ 11 thread section.