# OpenMP and C++11 multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, openmp, hpc

I am currently working on a project that mixes high-performance computing (HPC) and interactivity.
As such, the HPC part relies on OpenMP (mainly for-loops with lots of identical computations) but it is included in a larger framework with a GUI and multithreading, currently achieved with c++11 threads (`std::thread` and `std::async`).

I have read [Does OpenMP play nice with C++ promises and futures?](http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1421) and [Why do c++11 threads become unjoinable when using nested OpenMP pragmas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197510/why-do-c11-threads-become-unjoinable-when-using-nested-openmp-pragmas) that it is no good idea to mix OpenMP and C++11 threads, but so far it has been working for me.
For different reasons, I would like to improve on this, but I am not sure which strategy to adopt.

At [OpenMP vs C++11 threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258037/openmp-vs-c11-threads), I read that replacing OpenMP by `std::thread` has a considerable impact on performance due to creation and destruction of threads, but I couldn't find anything about replacing OpenMP acceleration by task-based parallelism with `std::async`. In my opinion, this should be faster than `std::thread` because then the thread managing is done by the operating system, but I am not convinced yet that this is applicable. I haven't tried it yet because it would involve loads of refactoring and I would have liked to hear other opinions first.

Do you have any experience with reconciling HPC and interactivity? In your eyes, should `std::async` be comparably fast to OpenMP?

Comment: "this should be faster than std::thread because then the thread managing is done by the operating system" <-- `std::thread` is also "managed by the operating system". Ultimately, both OpenMP and `std::thread` are wrapping the OS native threading facilities. Nothing intrinsically makes either one of them more or less native.

Comment: What I meant is that the OS has more freedom how to execute the task with a call to `std::async` than with `std::thread`, if I remember correctly what Scott Meyers says in Effective Modern C++. Thus I thought that the OS looks itself whether thread creation, destruction, etc is needed or not and that in the end performance should be better. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837696/can-i-safely-use-openmp-with-c11)? On the topic of reconciliation, have you considered having your HPC code run in a separate process and then have the GUI talk to it via some sort of IPC? Also, OpenMP is not the only multiprocessing option - there are Intel TBB, Microsoft C++ AMP, etc.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks, your answer there is definitely helpful!